# unable to send mail with cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I start in cakephp, my worry is that when I try to send a mail I have the following error:

```
 Network is unreachable
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 155 → CakeSocket->connect()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 95 → SmtpTransport->_connect()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1173 → SmtpTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP/Controller/OnlinesController.php line 114 → CakeEmail->send(string)
[internal function] → OnlinesController->felicitation()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 491 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(OnlinesController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(OnlinesController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 111 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Here is my controller

```
 <?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class ContactController extends AppController {

    public function felicitation()
    {
        $email = new CakeEmail('default');
        $email->transport('smtp');
        $email
            ->from('xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.org')
            ->to(['xxxxxx@xxxxx.com' => 'My Website'])
            ->subject('Contact')
            ->send('test mail');
    }

}
```

Then my email.php file

```
<?
public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'SMTP',
        'host' => 'myhost',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'domaine@domaine.com',
        'password' => '*********',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',

    );
    ?>
```

I think I have all try, I do not know what to do now so thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried using the credentials to send an email from something like Outlook to check they work? This isn't really something people can easily help you with here. It might be a good idea to wrap the code that sends the email in a `try {} catch (Exception $e) {}` block, so that your app doesn't completely fail if the email network goes offline.

Comment: I tried this method, unfortunately I get no error message.